# ReSharper - How to show custom snippet in IntelliSense

Tags: resharper, intellisense

I've created a custom snippet that contains a shortcut `proplto`. If I hit Ctrl-K, Ctrl-X and open My Code Snippets I can select my snippet. I can also type `proplto` in code, hit TAB and the snippet is inserted. However, I can't find a way to display my snippet in IntelliSense. It shows `prop` and `propg` but not my `proplto`. I tried adding my snippet by going to **Resharper > Templates Explorer**, selecting **C#** and importing my snippet file. It says "No templates of type 'Live Templates' found in the file.'

VS2013 Ultimate
ReSharper 8.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ReSharper Live Templates feature does not support Microsoft Code Snippets. So, you need to create a new live template manually in `ReSharper | Template Explorer | C# | New` and type needed code there. More info how to create Live Templates you may find [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Creating_a_Live_Template.html)

After you adding `proplto` Live Template to Templates Manager, it will be available in IntelliSense.

**ReSharper 9.0:**
ReSharper>Tools>Templates Explorer

Comment: Is there a way to disable ReSharper IntelliSense? I've tried enabling Auto list members and Parameter information in VS settings, but they get disabled automatically. Looks like ReSharper is hijacking IntelliSense.

Comment: To disable ReSharper IntelliSense and enable VS one, please tick "Visual Studio" option here ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | General. Then enable "Auto list members" and "Parameter information" in VS settings

Comment: Thank you for this answer as I did **not** want to disable Resharper intellisense