# Prism Snippets not working in Visual Studio 2017 with ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, prism

I am using Visual Studio 2017 along with the Prism Template Pack.

Prism snippets were working correctly until I installed Resharper. Now the only way I can insert prism snippet is by

> Edit -> Intellisens -> InsertSnippet [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>K , X</kbd>].

They are not popping up in Intellisense, and double tab does not work either when I type the snippet. I tried to disable/enable Prism Template Pack and reinstalling it, but without any success.

Can someone have any tips on how to get them working again, without retyping them as standard visual studio snippets?

P.S Visual Studio snippets `(prop,propg)` are working correctly.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am facing exactly the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, as I recall I just copied them to Visual Studio snippets

Answer (score 6):

Funny! Juts right now! I had the same problem! I searched and found these QA in there:
[How to disable ReSharper property code autocomplete/code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402531/how-to-disable-resharper-property-code-autocomplete-code-snippet)
&
[ReSharper - How to show custom snippet in IntelliSense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631439/resharper-how-to-show-custom-snippet-in-intellisense)

In both answers, they said either do:

- Disable `Resharper` code snippet to use `Visual Studio` code snippet
- From Visual Studio go to `ReSharper | Template Explorer | C# | New Template` menu and create new code Snippet for Resharper.

which I prefer the 2nd way more. To know more about [Template Explorer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Creating_a_Live_Template.html) in Resharper, you can read about it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Creating_a_Live_Template.html).

But especially for our problems! I used below steps to add [Prism](https://prismlibrary.github.io/) code snippets to Resharper: (Also, You can do the same thing for [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) code snippets or ...)

1. **Find Prism code snippets files folder location.** (Or MvvMLight or ...): I think the easiest way to do that is to go to: `Visual Studio | [Menu] Tools | Code Snippets Manager... | [Language]CSharp | Select Prism from tree`, then Copy and paste its `Location` into `Windows Explorer` address bar. Then, You will have all code snippets files of `Prism`.
2. **Open any `*.snippet` file** that you need to add it into Resharper with your text editor.
3. **Create a Resharper template for your Prism code snippet.** From Visual Studio, go to `[Menu]ReSharper | Tools | Template Explorer...` Then from `Templates Explorer` window/Tab select C# language(from Scopes panel) and click on [image: Resharper - New Template - Toolbar Icon] icon in toolbar. It will open a `Template <No Name>` tab inside the Visual Studio. Something look like below image:

[image]

4. **Copy original code snippet from Prism file or write it yourself.** From `*.snippet` file that you open in step 2 in your text editor, Copy lines from `<Code Language="csharp">` section between `<![CDATA[` and `$end$]]>` as I show it in below image, Then paste it into `Visual Studio | Template <No Name>` tab:

[image]

5. **You must give it a `Shortcut` name and optionally a `Description` then hit the `Save` button in Visual Studio.** (you can use the same codes from `*.snippet` file or change it as you wish!) I change it to this to make Resharper more happier!!! lol:

[image]

Done!

In my case, If I type `propp` and press Tab key once, It will create Prism Preoperty template for me! I Hope this help someone else too !

Happy Coding!